# Can't get modernIE's vagrant specific box to work with vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, provisioning

I recently discovered that Microsoft has provided a "Vagrant" option for downloading their modernIE Windows machines from [microsoft developer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/) and since I've been working with Vagrant to get some Windows environments running, I thought it'd be a nice shortcut and perhaps alleviate the expired licensing issues I've been having with the Windows boxes already available through Vagrant. However, it hasn't been smooth.

First, the downloaded box filename had a bunch of spaces that needed to be removed in order to prevent Ruby from exploding. I did that and was able to get the box added to Vagrant but now Vagrant gets stuck waiting for the machine to boot. The VM actually boots fine in the background but Vagrant times out because it can no longer communicate with the VM. The set timeout is several minutes beyond what it takes for the machine to boot.

Does anyone know how to fix this without locking in a license expiration date? Am I doing something wrong or did Microsoft create these Vagrant box VM's without actually checking to see if they run with Vagrant?

```
Host OS: El Capitan
Vagrant version: 1.8.1
Box: MSEdge - Win10TH2.box
VirtualBox version: 5.0.16
```

VagrantFile snippet:

```
config.vm.define "crap", autostart: false do |win|
  win.vm.box = "~/win10.box"  # Renamed from "MSEdge - Win10_TH2.box"
  win.vm.communicator = "winrm"
  win.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.11.7"
  win.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "crap"
    v.gui = true
  end
end
```

Error:

```
Bringing machine 'crap' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> crap: Importing base box '~/win10.box'...
==> crap: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> crap: Setting the name of the VM: crap
==> crap: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> crap: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    crap: Adapter 1: nat
==> crap: Forwarding ports...
    crap: 5985 (guest) => 55985 (host) (adapter 1)
    crap: 5986 (guest) => 55986 (host) (adapter 1)
==> crap: Booting VM...
==> crap: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    crap: WinRM address: 127.0.0.1:55985
    crap: WinRM username: vagrant
    crap: WinRM execution_time_limit: PT2H
    crap: WinRM transport: plaintext
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Answer (score 4):

If one want to use a Windows Vagrant box, then it´s most likely he want´s to stay with [WinRM Vagrant configuration](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/winrm_settings.html)n. So the answer of [cdwilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162349/cdwilson) points to SSH and didn´t satisfy me.

Additionally both [mr-rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5401781/mr-rogers) and [cdwilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162349/cdwilson) are wrong - the Vagrant boxes from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/ come with WinRM preinstalled and configured, just have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372(v=vs.85).aspx) or [here](https://gist.github.com/andreptb/57e388df5e881937e62a).

The last answer here was to craft a custom Vagrant box, which I also couldn´t follow in more professional scenarios.

But there´s help (sadly it´s manual effort, till Microsoft will pre-configure it correctly): We have to change the **Network List Management Policies**.

For that you need to manually boot the VM with getting the timeout error, go into *Local Security Policy* / *Network List Management Policies*, double klick on `Network`, go to tab `Network Location` and set the `Location type` to *private* and the `User permissions` to *User can change location*.

That´s all, now assuming a [correct Vagrantfile with WinRM configuration](https://github.com/jonashackt/ansible-windows-springboot/blob/master/Vagrantfile), the `vagrant up` will work without any errors.

But [mr-rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5401781/mr-rogers)  is right, please upvote the [microsoft developer FEEDBACK](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/11605572-update-vagrant-vms-and-package-ready-for-winrm)!

Answer (score 2):

I create a Vagrantfile is able to configure WinRM automatically on the box distributed by Microsoft. In other words this Vagrantfile is able to:

- Disable firewall (the box distributed by Microsoft is configured with
  firewall enabled by default);
- Change Network location type to "Work
  network" (the box distributed by Microsoft is configured as "Public
  network" by default);
- Enable WinRM.

https://github.com/danielmenezesbr/modernie-winrm

Comment: The box comes with WinRM aktivated already ([check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41471865/4964553)) and firewall should´nt be a problem for Vagrant. So the only thing that´s needed here is to change the Network List Management Policies. I think your Ruby implementation looks well done, but is a bit to much for the problem and a bit too "custom-made" for me. With my latest Windows Docker Container experiments I needed a neewer build than the modernIE boxes provided and went with [packer.io](https://www.packer.io/) to provide me a Vagrant box, which I now prefer over modernIE boxes...

Comment: @jonashackt Thank you for your feedback. While it is not necessary to disable the firewall here, In some circumstances it is necessary to do. For example, if you want to install a selenium node which will connect to a selenium grid, you will need to disable the firewall or change the firewall rules.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using virtualBox image downloaded from MS??

Could you open virtualBox and login into that VM in the first time executing `vagrant up`?? I found that the images downloaded from MS will prompt message about 'update'. If you execute `vagrant up` in commandLine. The prompt won't be dismissed. So it timeout.

Only first time execution encounter this, From my experience.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I'm using the correct box form MS. As for prompts, I fire up the GUI when I run `vagrant up` and it loads up without any issue without any prompts or messages. Just boots good ol' windows like normal

Answer (score 1):

The vagrant machines provided at [developer.microsoft.com](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/) are natively built with SSH access (not WinRM), but that does not mean they can be provisioned with SSH out of the gate.

Here is the error I am getting (because sudo is not installed):

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: IEUser
    default: SSH auth method: password
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/User/Desktop/Vagrant Boxes/8.1
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mkdir -p C:\Users\IEUser>

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

sh: sudo: command not found
```

You can use winrm if you login with SSH (via vagrant ssh; password is Passw0rd!) and issue these commands:

```
cmd /c "reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /d 0 /t REG_DWORD /f /reg:64"
powershell "Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex ((Get-NetConnectionProfile).InterfaceIndex) -NetworkCategory Private"
cmd /c "winrm quickconfig -q -force"
cmd /c 'winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="512"}'
cmd /c 'winrm set winrm/config @{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}'
cmd /c 'winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
cmd /c 'winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}'
cmd /c "sc config WinRM start= auto"
cmd /c 'netsh firewall add portopening TCP 5985 "Port 5985"'
cmd /c 'winrm set winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP @{Port="5985"} '
```

Maybe Windows can repackage these machines soon. Upvoting [this developer FEEDBACK](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/11605572-update-vagrant-vms-and-package-ready-for-winrm) may help.

[microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the Answer above WinRM has to be enabled. 
To avoid the steps described there evertime, I create a derived VagrantBox.

This Vagrantbox enables WinRM (and RDP) by default, so that it will fire up without modifications (https://atlas.hashicorp.com/mrh1997/boxes/vanilla-win7-32bit):

```
vagrant init mrh1997/vanilla-win7-32bit
vagrant up
```

You can use following commands to connect to the box:

```
vagrant powershell   # commandline via WinRM
vagrant rdp          # GUI via RDP
vagrant ssh          # commanline via SSH
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, boxes downloaded from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ come with SSH enabled by default.  However, they don't match the default SSH configuration vagrant expects.

Specifically, `config.ssh.insert_key = false` is not mentioned in any answers above:

> Vagrant is configured to generate a random keypair and insert it
>   onto the guest machine, but it appears Vagrant doesn't know how to do
>   this with your guest OS. Please disable key insertion by setting
>   `config.ssh.insert_key = false` in the Vagrantfile.
>
> After doing so, run `vagrant reload` for the setting to take effect.
>
> If you'd like Vagrant to learn how to insert keys on this OS, please
>   open an issue with details about your environment.

The following configuration options gave me working SSH access to a brand new Win10 VM downloaded today:

```
config.vm.guest = :windows
config.vm.boot_timeout = 600
config.vm.graceful_halt_timeout = 600
config.ssh.username = "IEUser"
config.ssh.password = "Passw0rd!"
config.ssh.insert_key = false
```

Here is the output:

```
$ vagrant up --provider virtualbox
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'msdev-win10'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: msdev-win10_default_1471207782454_14791
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: IEUser
    default: SSH auth method: password
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 5.0.20
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.1
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/chris/Projects/vagrant/msdev-win10
$ vagrant ssh
==> default: The machine you're attempting to SSH into is configured to use
==> default: password-based authentication. Vagrant can't script entering the
==> default: password for you. If you're prompted for a password, please enter
==> default: the same password you have configured in the Vagrantfile.
IEUser@127.0.0.1's password: 
-sh-4.1$
```

Comment: FYI, there is an official Windows 10 box on Atlas https://atlas.hashicorp.com/Microsoft/ but it does not have WinRM enabled.